# Should the synonym between [spellcasting] and [spells] be broken?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonymization

I ask this question because I have asked questions lately that play on the spell*casting* mechanics of *Anima: Beyond Fantasy* lately, that nonetheless have almost nothing to do with a particular spell or spells in the space of possible answers, e.g. [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/147407/what-ways-are-there-to-increase-ones-spellcasting-attribute-for-spellcasting-pu).

However, a question about getting a spellcasting attribute as high as possible clearly *is* about spellcasting, and I can't just not tag that, especially since there are particular points in the rules where "I'm using this attribute for spellcasting" *matters* - except it then is tagged [spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spells)!

Thus, I'd like to suggest we break the synonym between [spellcasting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spellcasting) and [spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spells).  It's not the same thing.

Comment: Isn't this why we left [spells] and [magic] separate?

Comment: @Oblivious Sage you tell me, I didn't even know we *had* a [magic] tag.

Comment: Related: [What's the difference between the 'magic' and 'spells' tags?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3199/whats-the-difference-between-the-magic-and-spells-tags), [Why can't \[magic\] sit with a more specific tag?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7633/why-cant-magic-sit-with-a-more-specific-tag)

Comment: The consensus on this question seems to be to break the synonym. What do we have to do to get it done?

Comment: @linksassin I sent up a custom flag - maybe that will do it?

Comment: @Stackstuck That was the right call, the flag brought this to the diamond team's attention. We're evaluating.

Comment: ...What does evaluating mean in this context?

Comment: @Stackstuck Basically sanity checking to make sure it's fine to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Tag Edit

Since this synonym break has been completed, I've taken a crack at editing the tag for this.

> For questions relating to the process of casting spells within a game.
>   Including, but not limited to: spell casting mechanics, improving
>   likelihood of success when casting a spell, interrupting spell
>   casting, and mechanics surrounding spellcasting attributes (when
>   applicable by system).

I concur with the others that treating these two tags as synonymous probably originates from a D&D centric mindset, which is not appropriate. However, I think the tag has broad applicability that can extend to include questions relating to D&D, so I've attempted to reflect that within the edit.

Comment: I've slightly edited the wording, and also edited the tag wiki for [tag:spells] and [tag:magic] to mention the [tag:spellcasting] tag.

Answer (score 16):

I’m not a fan of having them synonymised, for pretty much the reasons you give.

There are some games where spellcasting = spells (D&D being the big one), but that’s not true for other games, so having them be synonyms always struck me as a bit D&D-centric.

I think there’s room for questions about [spellcasting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spellcasting) (the activity and process in rules and/or fiction) separate from [spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spells) (specific formalised bundles of effects).

It might be a distinction that’s not clear to a majority whose games of choice don’t make that distinction though, so it could be friction-y for the community to manage them as separate tags in practice. I think it’s worth a try though, to see if maybe that concern isn’t a real problem.

Answer (score 7):

## We should break the synonym

My question [How does the Variant: Spell Points system from the DMG affect game balance?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/147991/48759) was clearly an example were the [spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spells) was inappropriate. Nothing in my question is related to a spell or its effects. [spellcasting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spellcasting) would have been the correct tag but we can't use it because it is a synonym.

I  can't imagine this is the only such case where this has happened. After breaking them I believe [spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spells) will still be the more common tag, but [spellcasting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spellcasting) has its own use that deserves a tag.

Additionally both tags are distinct from [magic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic) as a concept. All three tags should exist separately.